# Regex Matching defined tags in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i have this string

```
 This is a <143>sample</143> regex <143>pa<665>t</665>tern</143> selection <143>by</143> tags in <128>c#</128> and my <132>name</132> is <175>Vincent</175>
```

and i supposed to just get the match by tags. im using it for highlighting text.

Expected output:

```
<143>sample</143>
<143>pa<665>t</665>tern</143>
<665>t</665>
<143>by</143>
<128>c#</128>
<132>name</132>
<175>Vincent</175>
```

i tried this regex pattern:

```
<(143|128|132|175)>.*</(143|128|132|175)>
```

but it will print all the result as match, the whole string.

any help please.

---

**Follow up question**

instead of getting the whole line of match, can i get the text inside the tag alone? like i just get **sample** instead of **<143>sample<`/143>**

Comment: ah yeah i forgot.. it is nested tags

Comment: In that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: well.. THIS IS NOT MATCHING HTML TAGS

Comment: Have you tried treating it as XML ?

Comment: The idea is still the same. Unless you're using a regex engine which supports recursion, regexp is really the wrong tool for the job. Even when your regexp engine does support recursive regexp, there are less nightmarish, more maintainable ways of doing this.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Can XML tags start with digits? I was looking [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) and it didn't seem to be allowed.

Comment: @MarkByers - No, probably not. Maybe use a regex to insert a `'_'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two changes should help you:

- Use [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) matching (`.*?`).
- Use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex) (`\1`) so that you only match the same start and end tag.

Try this:

```
<(143|128|132|175)>.*?</\1>
```

Regarding "ah yeah i forgot.. it is nested tags": then it's probably not wise to use regular expressions. Nested tags isn't a regular langauge.

Comment: The back-reference is a nice touch, but not really needed.

Comment: .. unless it's nested tags. In which case it will come in handy. :)

Comment: ahh.. so i'd better change the idea of making it to nested tags.. well, the solution <(143|128|132|175)>.*?</\1> is working.. thanks sir..

Comment: hello can i continue with the follow up question? without creating another thread.

Comment: @vrynxzent: it's usually better to create a new question. You can add a link to this question if it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said, you should use the lazy matching here. It is achieved by appending `?` to your quantifier. In your case it is `*`.

Further, in order to simplify your work you could use the named capture. It is fully supported in the .NET. Here is a sample code

```
var target = @"This is a <143>sample</143> regex <143>pattern</143> selection <143>by</143> tags in <128>c#</128> and my <132>name</132> is <175>Vincent</175>";
var pattern = new Regex("<(143|128|132|175)>(?<Content>.*?)</\\1>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var result = pattern.Matches(target);
for (var j = 0; j < result.Count; j++) {
    var capts = result[j].Groups["Content"].Captures;
    for (var i = 0; i < capts.Count; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(capts[i].Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the .* is greedy..

You can either make it non-greedy by adding a ?: `.*?`

or

You can make it match anything but the '>': `[^<]*`

I usually go for the last one cause it is easier to remember and works in most cases..